# matching a string and appending a new one to it

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the following file:

```
NbV1Ch01        transdecoder    gene    802292  803490  .       +       .       ID=STRG.1;Name=ORF%20type%3A5prime_partial%20len%3A222%20%28%2B%29%2Cscore%3D55.19%2CXP_009619919.1%7C95.4%7C9.7e-113%2Cperoxidase%7CPF00141.23%7C3.1e-67%2CBaculo_PEP_C%7CPF04513.12%7C0.049%2CBaculo_PEP_C%7CPF04513.12%7C5.7e%2B02
NbV1Ch01        transdecoder    mRNA    802292  803490  .       +       .       ID=STRG.1.1.p1;Parent=STRG.1;Name=ORF%20type%3A5prime_partial%20len%3A222%20%28%2B%29%2Cscore%3D55.19%2CXP_009619919.1%7C95.4%7C9.7e-113%2Cperoxidase%7CPF00141.23%7C3.1e-67%2CBaculo_PEP_C%7CPF04513.12%7C0.049%2CBaculo_PEP_C%7CPF04513.12%7C5.7e%2B02
NbV1Ch01        transdecoder    exon    802292  802491  .       +       .       ID=STRG.1.1.p1.exon1;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1
NbV1Ch01        transdecoder    CDS     802294  802491  .       +       0       ID=cds.STRG.1.1.p1;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1
NbV1Ch01        transdecoder    exon    802781  802946  .       +       .       ID=STRG.1.1.p1.exon2;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1
NbV1Ch01        transdecoder    CDS     802781  802946  .       +       0       ID=cds.STRG.1.1.p1;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1
NbV1Ch01        transdecoder    exon    803048  803490  .       +       .       ID=STRG.1.1.p1.exon3;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1
NbV1Ch01        transdecoder    CDS     803048  803349  .       +       2       ID=cds.STRG.1.1.p1;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1
NbV1Ch01        transdecoder    three_prime_UTR 803350  803490  .       +       .       ID=STRG.1.1.p1.utr3p1;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1
```

I have e.g. this `cds.STRG.1.1.p1;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1`. How is it possible to change it to `ID=STRG.1.1.p1.cds;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you want to remove leading `cds.` and prepend it before `;` as `.cds` while also prefixing `ID=`? Please explain in greater details what you want (and preferably what you tried so far)!

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 0):

The KISS approach:

```
sed -e 's|cds.|ID=|g' -e 's|p1;|p1.cds;|g' file
```

That uses sed to replace `cds.` with `ID=` and  then replace `p1;` with `p1.cds;`.

The output:

```
ID=STRG.1.1.p1.cds;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1
```

If that does what you want and it's coming from a file that you want to change, you can edit it in place with

```
sed -i -e 's|cds.|ID=|g' -e 's|p1;|p1.cds;|g' string
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question because I had a mistake which leads that your solution changed more strings in the file.

Comment: @user977828 I have updated the answer. You've changed the question many times since you've posted it. Are you sure that it is now what you want? Just to point out, the file doesn't contain `cds.STRG.1.1.p1;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1`. It actually contains `ID=cds.STRG.1.1.p1;Parent=STRG.1.1.p1`.

Comment: Not quite, because I got `NbV1Ch01 transdecoder mRNA 802292 803490 . + . ID=STRG.1.1.p1.cds;Parent=STRG.1;` but this line should have remained without `.cds`. Does the KISS approach depends on each other?

Comment: @user977828 The string that you are trying to replace doesn't exist in that file. Add the expected output to your question so that it's more clear. Make sure that it's what you want so that you can get an answer that works